# Allow marking text as fixed width font

Tags: support, markdown, fonts

There are times when using a fixed-width font adds significantly to the readability of the text.  It would be nice if we could mark a block of text as using a fixed-width font.  **I know this can be done with the Code Sample markdown, but that syntax colors it and prevents other markdowns, like bold and italic, from working**.  Sometimes I just want a fixed-width font.

Okay, this works:

```
bold italic strike
```

Just have to use HTML instead of markdown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or you can use pre

```
Some fixed width text with formatting
```

was created with:

```
<pre>
Some fixed width text <em>with formatting</em> 
</pre>
```

See [the help file](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for all the editor details.

Comment: Cool. That takes care of italics, but the <b> tag doesn't seem to work.  However, the <strike> tag does.

Comment: Try <strong> instead of <b>.

Answer (score 4):

```
<pre> tags seem to do the trick
```

following text does not have to be fixed width

The Markdown looks like:

```
<pre>&lt;pre&gt; tags seem to <b>do</b> the <i>trick</i></pre>

following text does not have to be fixed width
```

Comment: But then all the code following it is fixed width as well.  Put a closing tag on it and that italic won't be italic anymore.

Comment: See my edit: this is not the case.

Comment: It shows up okay for me; my fixed-width font is Consolas but I know some other fonts don't distinguish bold very well.  Maybe thats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As others note, `<pre>` works. But i wouldn't mind seeing `<tt>` supported, for those occasions where you want to publish console output in an appropriate fixed-width font.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `<code>`code`</code>` fixed-width?

`asdfoao2 23r0 qBWEFwja

ao293f8S w345 AESFQ2er`

Comment: You can't bold/italicize items in a code block. Also it may try to apply syntax highlighting on certain words.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine for me:

`<code><b> Bold    multiple spaces with &nbsp; 
</b></code>`

```
<code>&lt;code&gt;<b>&lt;b&gt; Bold&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;multiple spaces with &amp;nbsp; &lt;/b&gt;</b>&lt;/code&gt;</code>
```